# не получается применить созданную функцию

Tags: python

**код вне функции работает корректно, переводит строку в список и убирает лишние символы**

```
my_str = '32 431 348 453  45'

my_list = list(my_str)

my_list = [i for i in my_list if i not in [' ', '4', '5']]

my_list = [int(i) for i in my_list]

print(my_list)

# [3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 8, 3]
```

**но внутри функции не работает и не возвращает никаких ошибок**

```
def str_to_int(r1, r2):

    my_list = list(my_str)
    my_list = [i for i in my_list if i not in [' ', 'r1', 'r2']]
    my_list = [int(i) for i in my_list]

    print(my_list)

my_str = '32 431 348 453  45'

str_to_int(4, 5)

# [3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 8, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Там разные условия в `if i not in `

Comment: скопировал с ошибкой, исправил

Comment: если передавать переменную в кавычках то вы получите имя переменной, а не ее значение (наверное)

Comment: Попробуйте убрать кавычки от переменных в [' ', 'r1', 'r2']

Comment: Спасибо @Стас , действительно параметры функции нужно было в кавычках передавать. str_to_int('1', '2') а из функции наоборот убрать кавычки not in [' ', r1, r2]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на ваш дополнительный вопрос: 
Чтобы задать произвольное количество аргументов у функции, можно объявить её вот так:

```
def str_to_int(*r):
    ...
```

Тогда r внутри функции будет кортежем из её аргументов. Чтобы преобразовать это в список, можно, например, сделать так:

```
def str_to_int(*r):
    r1 = [' '] + list(r)
```

К тому же другие фрагменты можно переписать с использованием встроенных средств языка. Можно заменить

```
[int(i) for i in my_list]
```

на

```
list(map(int, my_list))
```

, `map()` применяет первый аргумент — функцию ко всем элементам второго аргумента — итерируемого контйнера.

Проверку на вхождение в цикле можно реализовать с помощью `filter()`, но тут уже придётся использовать лямбда-выражение

Comment: спасибо, получилось.

Comment: не подскажешь как присвоить переменной получившийся список чисел? думал будет достаточно оператора =, но мне возвращает None если вывожу новую переменную через print

Comment: @Jimmy достаточно просто написать <code>return my_list </code> в последней строчке функции

Comment: да, я первым делом так попробовал сделать, но мне почему-то возвращает: `name 'my_list' is not defined`

Comment: [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/raw/N5JfVNTG) @artaxerx

Comment: А, вы просто на выходе не присвоили ничему значение функции `str_to_intlist()`, поэтому `print` и не знает, что ему печатать. То есть, должно быть нечто вроде  `my_list2 = str_to_intlist(...); print(my_list2)`

Comment: спасибо большое, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

параметры функции нужно было в кавычках передавать

```
str_to_int('1', '2')
```

а из функции наоборот убрать кавычки `not in [' ', r1, r2]]`

возникает другой вопрос, чтобы сделать функцию гибкой и не задавать жестко только 2 параметра как в примере, можно ли как-то в одном параметре передать сразу 2 и более значения:

вместо `r1` -> `'4'` и `r2` -> `'5'` как сейчас, передать сразу `r1` -> `'4'`, `'5'`, `'8'`

когда пробую, пишет "str_to_int() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"